# Mercurial over ssh with config file

Tags: mercurial, ssh

Say I have the following ssh **.config** file:

```
Host host_nickname
    User xxx
    HostName yyy.zz.vvv
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p
```

In case you are not familiar with **ControlMaster** or **ControlPath**, here is the description from the [ssh_config manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5):

```
ControlMaster:
         Enables the sharing of multiple sessions over a single network
         connection.  When set to ``yes'', ssh(1) will listen for connec-
         tions on a control socket specified using the ControlPath argu-
         ment.  Additional sessions can connect to this socket using the
         same ControlPath with ControlMaster set to ``no'' (the default).
         These sessions will try to reuse the master instance's network
         connection rather than initiating new ones, but will fall back to
         connecting normally if the control socket does not exist, or is
         not listening.
```

In Mercurial, if you want to push or pull from a repository, you could just type the following:

```
hg push ssh://user@example.com/hg/
```

#### Now, my question:

I would like to ask Mercurial to push (or pull) against a repository at `/path/to/repository` on the server corresponding to my ssh config entry **host_nickname**. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look under `hg help urls` you'll find

```
ssh://[user@]host[:port]/[path][#revision]
```

So, assuming that `/path/to/repository` works from your login dir on the remote machine, then type

```
hg [push|pull] ssh://host_nickname/path/to/repository
```

This works because `hg` isn't doing the name resolution; `ssh` is, and you've specified the correspondence between `host_nickname` and the real `HostName`.  Also, `ControlMaster` won't affect this, as that just allows multiplexing over a single ssh connection.  Note, if `hg` isn't in your remote `PATH`, then you need to specify it via `--remotecmd /path/to/hg`.